# Reheat only a few pieces of meat pie

Tags: meat, pie, reheating

My meat pie has already been cut and there are only a few pieces left.

*How can I reheat these pieces so the sides don’t dry out?*

Answer (score 2):

Easy-peasy:

- Wet your hand
- Rub moisture all over the pieces
- Wrap them all cosily together in:

  - Aluminium foil if a normal oven
  - Microwave-safe kitchen foil if a microwave oven
- Bake as per original instructions